# How to download an image using URLSessionDownload?

Tags: swift, url, download, nsurlsession

I need to download an image from a server and to show it inside my app. I choose to use `URLSessionDownload` protocol in order to get the download status and progress through all the process. This is my code:

```
var downloadBGTask: URLSessionDownloadTask!
var downloadBGSession: URLSession!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.downloadBGSession = {
        let downloadBGSessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "downloadBGSession")
        return URLSession(configuration: downloadBGSessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    }()

    self.downloadBGTask = self.downloadBGSession.downloadTask(with: "http.. ETC .png")
    self.downloadBGTask.resume()
}
```

Protocols

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){
    self.loadingLabel.text = "Loading (\((Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)) * 100)%)"
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("Download Completed")

    // How do I get the image I downloaded?
    // This code below doesn't even compile
    self.randomImg.image = UIImage(data: downloadTask.response!)
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` is the temporary file URL of the data. So you can do:

```
extension ViewController: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    ...

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("Download Completed")

        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: location)
        randomImg.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```

Or, you might save it to the caches folder before you use it, too (because the file `URL` in `location` is for a temporary file that will be removed as soon as you return):

```
/// Local file URL for cached image

let cachedImageFileURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    .appendingPathComponent("saved.png")
```

And then:

```
extension ViewController: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    ...

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("Download Completed")

        imageDownloadInProgress = false

        try! FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: cachedImageFileURL)
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: location)

        randomImg.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }

}
```

---

But the question is why you are doing a background `URLSession`. If you're going to do this, you have to do other things. For example, you app delegate must capture the completion handler in case the app wasn't running when the background request finished:

```
var backgroundRequestCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    backgroundRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

And then your view controller (if it's really going to be the `URLSessionDelegate`), must call this saved completion handler when the handling of the background session requests is done:

```
extension ViewController: URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.backgroundRequestCompletionHandler?()
    }
}
```

But if you're doing this, it doesn't make sense for `viewDidLoad` to always initiate a new download (as the download may have already been initiated by a prior invocation of the app). So before you initiate a download request, you'd probably want it to:

- look for existence of cached file from previous request; and
- check to see if download is in progress (having either saved this status in persistent storage or by using `URLSession` asynchronous method [`getTasksWithCompletionHandler(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411578-gettaskswithcompletionhandler).

Comment: You're totally right! I'm doing something pointless! My first aim was trying to download and show an image before an animation starts. But I didn't know how to handle if the connection was bad (maybe with a timeout)

Comment: @user3582537 - Introducing background sessions only makes it far more complicated. The completion block rendition of `dataTask` or `downloadTask` is far easier, IMHO. In those methods, you just check to see if the `Data` or the `URL` is non-`nil` and whether the `Error` reference is `nil`. But hopefully I've shown you how to use the `URL` that is passed back to you for download tasks.

Comment: Thanks! I choose this way because when I used dataTask with completion it called the "completion" block but it took about 2/3 seconds before showing the downloaded image. But maybe I should post another question for that. Thanks for your help and your patience

Comment: @user3582537 - Did you dispatch that UI update to the main queue? `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`. You can get weird delays if you try to do these UI updates from background queue without dispatching it back to the main queue.